# JobScheduler not working after setting time interval

Tags: android, timer, intervals, android-jobscheduler

I try to run JobScheduler for periodic interval 10 sec. e.g. builder.setPeriodic(10000). But not able to start TestJobService IntentService on button click and doesn't show any error message.

**Can any body help me.**

```
public void onClick(View v){
    ComponentName mServiceComponent = new ComponentName(this, TestJobService.class);
                JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(kJobId++, mServiceComponent);
                //Pass Parameter to Job Scheduler
                PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
                bundle.putString(DataDownloadService.EXTRA_PARAM_URL, DataDownloadService.URL);
                builder.setExtras(bundle)
                        .setPersisted(true);
                builder.setPeriodic(10000);//10 Seconds
                builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); 
                builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); 
                builder.setRequiresCharging(false);  is charging or not
                JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain **in detail** what "not able to start the scheduler" means. Note that a period of 10000 may be too short.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But not able to start TestJobService IntentService

`JobScheduler` does not work with an `IntentService`. It works with [a `JobService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html).